# Group items from list object based on id in each object of the lists using AngularJs v1.6/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a object containing list of item data. I need to group items based on stockTypeCd and display Product 1, Product 2 in one row and Product 3 in another row as it has a different stockTypeCd. Here is the sample JSON that am getting in Angular Controller from Java Rest services. I cannot change the way my json response from java. Here is the sample json

```
{  
   "availableItems":[  
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":200005,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":100005,
            "stockTypeCd":2,
            "name":"Product 1"
         },
      },
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":200006,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":100006,
            "stockTypeCd":2,
            "name":"Product 2"
         },
      },
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":220005,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":110005,
            "stockTypeCd":1,
           "name":"Product 3"
         },         
      }
   ]
}
```

When user clicks submit, i get a json like this one and i have to group elements and display in the UI table.

Comment: You could parse your json and change the data structure so you can do what you want.

Comment: What are the possible value of stockTypeCd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) to use `stock.stockTypeCd` as key.

This is a sample:

```
function groupItems(data) {
    var grouped = data.availableItems.reduce(function(result, current) {
      result[current.stock.stockTypeCd] = result[current.stock.stockTypeCd] || [];
      result[current.stock.stockTypeCd].push(current);
      return result;
    }, {});
    return grouped;
}
```

So, you can convert this:

```
{  
   "availableItems":[  
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":200005,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":100005,
            "stockTypeCd":2,
            "name":"Product 1"
         },
      },
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":200006,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":100006,
            "stockTypeCd":2,
            "name":"Product 2"
         },
      },
      {  
         "stockCategoryId":220005,
         "stock":{  
            "stockId":110005,
            "stockTypeCd":1,
           "name":"Product 3"
         },         
      }
   ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "stockCategoryId": 220005,
            "stock": {
                "stockId": 110005,
                "stockTypeCd": 1,
                "name": "Product 3"
            }
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "stockCategoryId": 200005,
            "stock": {
                "stockId": 100005,
                "stockTypeCd": 2,
                "name": "Product 1"
            }
        },
        {
            "stockCategoryId": 200006,
            "stock": {
                "stockId": 100006,
                "stockTypeCd": 2,
                "name": "Product 2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With the new array you can print the results in a html `table` by using this function:

```
function printResults(data) {
    var i, len, html = "<table border=\"1\">";
    html += "<thead><tr><th>stockTypeCd</th><th>Stock</th></thead><tbody>";
    for (item in data) {
      html += "<tr><td>";
      html += item;
      html += "</td><td><table>";
      len = data[item].length;
      if (len > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          html += "<tr><td><span>stockId: </span>";
          html += data[item][i].stock.stockId;
          html += "</td></tr><td><span>name: </span>";
          html += data[item][i].stock.name;
          html += "</td></tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
      }
      html += "</td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    return html;
}
```

So you can get this:

[image]

**Usage:**

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = printResults(groupItems(data));
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var data = {
    "availableItems": [{
        "stockCategoryId": 200005,
        "stock": {
          "stockId": 100005,
          "stockTypeCd": 2,
          "name": "Product 1"
        },
      },
      {
        "stockCategoryId": 200006,
        "stock": {
          "stockId": 100006,
          "stockTypeCd": 2,
          "name": "Product 2"
        },
      },
      {
        "stockCategoryId": 220005,
        "stock": {
          "stockId": 110005,
          "stockTypeCd": 1,
          "name": "Product 3"
        },
      }
    ]
  };

  function groupItems(data) {
    var grouped = data.availableItems.reduce(function(result, current) {
      result[current.stock.stockTypeCd] = result[current.stock.stockTypeCd] || [];
      result[current.stock.stockTypeCd].push(current);
      return result;
    }, {});
    return grouped;
  }

  function printResults(data) {
    var i, len, html = "<table border=\"1\">";
    html += "<thead><tr><th>stockTypeCd</th><th>Stock</th></thead><tbody>";
    for (item in data) {
      html += "<tr><td>";
      html += item;
      html += "</td><td><table>";
      len = data[item].length;
      if (len > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          html += "<tr><td><span>stockId: </span>";
          html += data[item][i].stock.stockId;
          html += "</td></tr><td><span>name: </span>";
          html += data[item][i].stock.name;
          html += "</td></tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
      }
      html += "</td></tr>";
    }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    return html;
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = printResults(groupItems(data));
})();
```

```css
#result table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#result table thead {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#daebf7, #9fbfe6);
}

#result table th,
#result table td {
  border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
}

#result table td span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Great demo @Danny!

Comment: Wonderful implementation

Answer (score 0):

This creates a map of `availableItems` using `stockTypeCd` as the key. You can iterate over it and apply any sort of business logic that you desire

```js
var data = {
  "availableItems": [{
      "stockCategoryId": 200005,
      "stock": {
        "stockId": 100005,
        "stockTypeCd": 2,
        "name": "Product 1"
      },
    },
    {
      "stockCategoryId": 200006,
      "stock": {
        "stockId": 100006,
        "stockTypeCd": 2,
        "name": "Product 2"
      },
    },
    {
      "stockCategoryId": 220005,
      "stock": {
        "stockId": 110005,
        "stockTypeCd": 1,
        "name": "Product 3"
      },
    }
  ]
}

// Map of stockTypeCd to availableItems
var groupedData = {};
data.availableItems.forEach(function(item) {
  // If map doesn't contain the stockTypeCd, create a new entry
  if (!groupedData.hasOwnProperty(item.stock.stockTypeCd)) {
    groupedData[item.stock.stockTypeCd] = []
  }
  groupedData[item.stock.stockTypeCd].push(item);
});

console.log(groupedData);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maaz!!